# What algorithm i use for a Wikipedia bot?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

i want to create a bot for Wikipedia which fight vandalism.
It's like spam detection but people can remove text or add text. I want to use machine learning to do this. I don't know which machine learning algorithm should i use.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea, but a good point to start would be to get a huge count of sample data.

Comment: @rekire I have already started but I do not know how to classify the data because there is removed text  and added text.

Comment: * in one edit .

Comment: A search with the terms "wikipedia vandalism detection" gives a lot of results. It's a topic which is quite well studied in research, you can find many articles on [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=wikipedia+vandalism+detection&btnG=&oq=wikipedia+vandalism)).

Comment: @Erwan thanks,  I'll take a look at it.